# Two MouseEvents for creating nodes and clearing them - JavaFX

Tags: javafx, mouseevent

This event handler to put objects on stage and after this happens I want to clear the stage and put a freshly created circle where mouse is pressed.

```
scene.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){    

         public void handle(final MouseEvent me){        
                 Circle circle = new Circle(50*Math.random());
                 Color c = new Color(Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random(),1.0);
                 circle.setFill(c);
                 root.getChildren.add(circle)  
               });

scene.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){    

         public void handle(final MouseEvent me){        
                 root.getChildren().clear();
               });
```

I am unable to achieve the effect of having one mouse click create a node and another mouse click to clear the former node. Is it possible to achieve this modifying these lines of code?

Answer (score 1):

```
scene.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){    

     @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        if(mouseEvent.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY)){
            if(mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 2){
                root.getChildren.clear();
            }
       }
   }
});
```